# Selecionar tema no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, temas

Quando eu seleciono um tema no Android Studio, como este Holo que mudei, ele altera o preview mas quando eu executo a aplicação no meu aparelho não muda nada. Alguém pode ajudar ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você precisa alterar no styles.xml. Da uma olhada nesse link http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/themes.html. Abs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só está a alterar o tema de previsualização do Android Studio.
para a alterar o tema da app tem de ir ao seu ficheiro AndroidManifest.xml

e na tag `application` altera o parametro theme.

```
<application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
```

Este é só um exemplo:
Para veres outros themes ou criares o teu personalizado vê o seguinte link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

Em styles.xml, você verá o tema usado em sua aplicação, como nesse exemplo:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Veja que o código acima possui cores que foram externalizadas no arquivo "colors.xml", que está na pasta "values", com o seguinte código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#E76D00</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E76D00</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#E76D00</color>

    <color name="colorTextView">#ff606060</color>
    <color name="colorTextViewDark">#ff020202</color>
</resources>
```

Já para editar o tema de seu aplicativo, o Android Studio disponibiliza um editor padrão para temas - com a IDE Android Studio aberta, vá ao menu `tools` > `Android` > `Theme Editor` e lá faça as alterações como desejar.

Agora é só teclar <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> e depois <kbd>CTRL+F9</kbd> para ver o resultado.